# Points in bounding box MySql using geospatial types

Tags: mysql, database, geospatial

I’m trying to query SQL to return points that fall within a bounding box. The best answer I have found is this sort of idea:

```
lng1 <= lng2 AND (lng1 <= lng AND lng <= lng2) /* both edges on same side */
OR
lng1 >  lng2 AND (lng1 <= lng OR  lng <= lng2) /* edges on opposite sides */
```

This can be seen here: [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c864787dea7198281b0bec8d5254e67)

However I’m using a newer version of MySQL where I am storing my coordinates as “points” type. I’ve been trying to understand if this newer version of MySQL (8) can allow me a better way to select rows with points within a bounding box, but I haven’t had any luck. Does this capability exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL can do this easily for simple bounding box, but it does not support antimeridian-crossing boxes, so this will be complicated.

If you did not have any boxes crossing antimedirian, you could simply write expression like

```
ST_Intersects(
  ST_MakeEnvelope(Point(lng1, lat1), Point(lng2, lat2)), 
  Point(lng, lat))
```

But since in MySQL ST_MakeEnvelope [only supports Cartesian CRS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-makeenvelope), you'll need to code for antimeridian-crossing boxes yourself, e.g. by constructing two boxes - one from lng1 to 180 and one from -180 to lng2.

Comment: I also suddenly found that MySQL does not support antimeridian-crossing boxes. Is this documented anywhere? I also tried to split it into 2 bounding boxes, but then a point with lng=180 (exactly) is not contained in any of these 2 bounding boxes (`MbrContains` returns 0). Looks like edge is not considered as "contains". I suppose I forced to split `point` column back to `lat`/`lng` columns... :-( Also even if solution with 2 bounding boxes will work, it is sub-optimal as `OR` prevents to effectively use SPATIAL index on `point` column...

Comment: It is kind of documented by the link above saying MySQL only supports Cartesian CRS - it is flat map CRSes, which know nothing about antimeridian. On the other hand, it should gladly accept lng=181 and lng=-181 that would safely include points exactly at the antimeridian.
As for solution to OR - you might try UNION ALL of two queries, one looking at the eastern hemisphere, one looking at the western one, then remove duplicates with GROUP BY. It is ugly, but might work with indices.